# Javers - Comparison ValueObjects which are null and object with empty list

Tags: java, null, comparison, javers, empty-list

I have such class:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
public class ValueObjectList {
    private List<DummyClass> dummyClassList;
}
```

And in main method 2 object of that class:

```
ValueObjectList valueObjectList1 = ValueObjectList.builder()
            .dummyClassList(new ArrayList<>())
            .build();

ValueObjectList valueObjectList2 = null;
```

I want to compare such object by Javers. What's the best way to treat these objects by javers as the same objects? Do I have to create my own comparator for this case? Maybe can I set such a configuration in JaversBuilder?

Comment: where is the problem? try to write a full test case https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#guidelines-for-bug-reporting

Comment: @BartekWalacik I want to define configuration(in JaversBuilder) so that, null valueobject and valueobject with empty list was treat as same value, but i don't know how. I want to do this in JaversBuilder because I can't use annotations in this project, because in reality this object are generated and I can't modify them. The above cases are just examples to introduce problem I am struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Custom Types and `CustomPropertyComparator`. See the javadoc for `CustomType`:

Custom Types are not easy to manage, use it as a last resort,
only for corner cases like comparing custom Collection types.

JaVers treats a Custom Type as a black box
and doesn't take any assumptions about its content or behaviour.
It's a "not modeled" type, somehow similar to unbounded wildcard `<?>`

Objects of Custom Type are compared by a `CustomPropertyComparator`.
Registering this comparator is the only way to map a Custom Type.

Custom Types are serialized to JSON using Gson defaults.

see `JaversBuilder#registerCustomType(Class, CustomPropertyComparator)`

Comment: I used eariel this solution(I created my own comparator implenting CustomPropertyComparator). However I thought that there is other easier and simplier way to solve this problem(using JaversBuilder). But thanks for your aswer